# Opening ArcGIS Pro data with definition queries and symbology in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-pro, symbology

I have a several datasets in ArcGIS Pro which I have queried and symbolised. I would like this exact same dataset with the same queries and symbology to be available in ArcMap as well. I was hoping to create a layer file, which would be possible to open in ArcMap, but it seems this function is not compatible. You can open layer files created in ArcMap in ArcGIS Pro, but not the other way round.

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by @CezarB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425562/open-arcgis-pro-data-with-definition-queries-and-symbology-in-arcmap/434982#comment694339_425562) a possible workaround from https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/saving-lyr-file-from-arcgis-pro/td-p/674162 is to:

> Publish the layer in ArcGIS online from Pro and then pull the
> published layer into ArcMap by logging onto ArcGIS online from inside
> ArcMap. You can then save it as a .lyr file.